# Where did the Python UI OpenGL API hide?

Tags: python, add-on

Twenty-ish moons ago there was hype about addons being able to do their own OpenGL UIs into panels. This was around the time custom icons became a thing. Now that I happen to need it, I can't find any trace of it. Did I just hallucinate the whole thing? I can find lots of tutorials about OpenGL in the 3D view though.

Comment: since blender 2.60 we have the bgl python module. Are you looking for that? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61699/how-to-draw-geometry-in-3d-view-window-with-bgl

Comment: Nope. I mean drawing into panels (or nodes to be even more specific) with some sort of custom gl, not into the 3D view. Or is there some way to draw into panels with bgl?