# Adding a skirt / border to object with sharp corners leaves gaps

Tags: modeling

I have an SVG that i made into an outline of an object (shape of Texas), but when i go to add a skirt / border to it the shrink/fatten leaves gaps in the border. Is there a way to expand a face evenly to where I get a smooth border.

Here are the steps I have taken

- Import SVG and create mesh object
- extruded the object so it has height
- selected the top faces so i can extrude again to have a smaller face
  for the border
- selected the smaller face from the step above and selected Shirnk/Fatten

Expected results:
I would like a smooth lip on the outside of the very top portion of an outline of an object
As you can see on sharp outside corners there are gaps and on sharp inside corners it expands into the interior of the shape.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Import SVG, do not convert to mesh, make it a 2d Curve, Use extrusion on the curve to give it thickness, bevel the curve.

Comment: The SVG is flat though. I need to give it height and then add a lip / skirt  to only the top of it.

Comment: An svg is a curve, curves can have extrusion. Set it in the Geometry tab. https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/3X/e/c/eccd5fcd94fe60759c29ae5515efab5b7a81db6a.jpg Read: https://easyblend.org/html/modeling/curves/editing/extrude.html

Comment: Thank you for the new knowledge about the 2d curve. However, beveling it just makes it fat and not the cross section I'm looking for. The cross section at any given vertical part should be like an upside down L not like a <> shape

Comment: do you have pictures of the kind of shape you want? Won't you have what you want with array + curve modifiers?

Comment: I'm a noob so I don't know all the options or the terminology of whats available. I'm learning fast but I'm still not up to speed with all the lingo or methods available. Imagine a cookie cutter of texas but with a lip around it so it adds support to the shape and allows the person to hold it better. I'll find a picture of an example.

Answer (score 1):

Import the svg curve.

Scale it to some size that is workable.

[image]
SVGs are imported as curve objects. You don't need to convert them to mesh in order to extrude, you can do that in the geometry section>extrude.

[image]

(I changed the color for visibility to the blue state that Texas should be)

Then create a new curve object, I will name it "Lip Curve" that has the profile shape you are looking for. Make it small, much smaller than the other object. To make sharp angles select two control points, press <kbd>V</kbd> to access the handle type menu, and select "vector"

[image]

[image]

Use the "Lip Curve" as taper object for the Texas Outline.

[image]

You can clean up the object a bit by lowering the resolution for the curve (in this case I lowered the preview resolution for the curve from 16 to 1)

[image]

Note that I'm getting a double lip on the object because this particular curve was created thicker in the vector drawing program (inkscape, illustrator, etc) So when it is imported into blender that thickness will be made out of two parallel curves to give it thickness.

[image]

To further refine the shape and do cleanup of overlapping segments convert to mesh and manually fix imperfections.

Comment: Thank you. This seems very promising but I'm not able to fill in the blanks yet because of my lack of experience.  I'm in edit mode on a curve. I'm trying to get the right angle but I'm not sure how. I've been searching on how to do that but I have not found it. I'm sure is simple. Every time i try to drag it, it makes and smooth curve not a sharp angle. I even selected vector like another link suggested but I do not see a difference. Can you expand on the creation of the "lip curve" section please.

Comment: See edited answer. It is impossible teach you to use blender in one post. Do some research on your own too,

Comment: I totally understand. I've been looking at tutorials but because blender is so massive I haven't found the specific recipe for what I'm trying to do. I've literally spent 4 hours trying to figure out the curve right angle part of your post. I've searched propably 50 permutations of search terms regarding that. I'm not one to just ask for a handout but I'm under a time constraint and needed to be force fed this one. I really appreciate you taking the time and if you post a BTC addy I'll give you some compensation.

Comment: Never post your email in sites like this. For any other questions please use the big blue Ask Queston box at the top.

Comment: When I create a Bezier curve i do not get multiple vertices like your gif. When i do whats posted here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8808/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-add-vertices-to-a-curve-at-a-specific-point I get an extra line to move around not like in your gif

Comment: So I'm able to "extend" the number of control points by clicking on one of the end control points and pressing "E". The curve is not flat like in the above gif. It looks like it is 3d so when I apply the bevel (also you mention taper object above but the highlight is on the bevel object) it makes the edge like a U even though the shape looks like an L.