# Distance to Viewport View-Camera

Tags: python, 3d-view

How can I get the distance between specific points in the 3D View and the virtual camera of my viewport?

Using the distance, I could select the closest or furthest (farthest) vertex/object from my perspective view.

---

<sup>Answering my own question, although I still don't know the difference between `perspective_matrix`, `window_matrix` and `view_matrix`. I also would prefer more explanation on why we don't need to use the inverted matrix.)

This question came up while creating [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144707/30849).</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: demo]
<sup>*Snapping an empty to the closest vertex of a cube. "Closest" meaning closest to the viewer.*</sup>

First, loop through the areas or obtain a [SpaceView3D](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html?highlight=spaceview3d) by other means. The type of this area returns `VIEW_3D`. It's first space will be a `VIEW_3D` space. This space has a [`region_3d`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html) property, which has a [`perspective_matrix`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D.perspective_matrix) property.

The `perspective_matrix` appears to be the perspective view transform matrix. Mutliple a 3D Vector by the matrix, to get its position relativ to the camera.

Here is a working sample.

```
import bpy

# function returning the closest vertex of 
# param 'ob' is an object in the scene with vertices
def get_closest_vertex_position(scene, ob):
    # get an area of type VIEW_3D
    areas = [a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type == 'VIEW_3D']
    if not len(areas):
        return

    region3d = areas[0].spaces[0].region_3d

    # get the view matrix
    view_mat_inv = region3d.view_matrix

    if region3d.is_perspective:
        vertices = [[v, (view_mat_inv*v.co).length] for v in ob.data.vertices]
    else:
        vertices = [[v, -(view_mat_inv*v.co).z] for v in ob.data.vertices]

    # use a lamda expression to get closest vertex
    return min(vertices, key = lambda x: x[1])[0].co
```

Comment: Cool.  Suggest doing this via a modal operator, a timer, or in  a draw callback on the 3dview space rather than with a _scene_update_pre_ . (_depsgraph_update_pre_ on 2.8)  handler.  If for instance have two windows open with different scenes will confuse the result above.

Comment: @bat Yes, definitely. This was merely a side product of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144707/30849). I used the modal operator there. I'll just remove the last line, so future readers won't get tempted.^^

Comment: Did you mean to type `view_matrix` in the descriptive paragraphs?

Comment: @Robin Actually, no. As stated in the question, I'm still confused about `perspective_matrix`, `window_matrix` and `view_matrix`. The code works view `perspective_matrix`, although I don't know why. If you could clarify, that would be great.

Comment: I think I'm just as confused as you.. I need to clear it up for myself. If I do, I'll let you know..

Comment: Following (as far as I can see) exactly the conventions described [here](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/405/notes/projections.pdf), viewing down -Z,  `view_matrix` is the xform from world space to viewpoint space (the inverse of the world xform of the viewpoint).. what `window_matrix`  is depends on whether your view is orthogonal or perspective, and in either case gives the xform from the current window-shaped frustum to a canonical view volume, a cube -1 to 1 in X,Y and Z,  viewpoint at 0. The `perspective_matrix` gives the 1st xform followed by the 2nd.

Comment: P.S. You can play with these by transforming a unit cube by them in a 3D view, but you won't see the perspective projection unless you use homogeneous coordinates; express your points as (X,Y,Z,1), and before going back to 3D, divide through by the last (W) value.