# looping through splines of a bezier circle, can only find 1 spline not 4

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes, mathematics, bezier-curves

I'm trying to port differential line growth to blender animation nodes following this example https://vimeo.com/169438763 .
I was suggested to work with splines in blender as it would be a lot simpler to working directly with meshes.

Right now I'm trying to create a function that loops through every spline of a bezier circle, and add a spline in between two splines when the distance between these two splines is larger than X.

To this effect I'm looping throughout the splines of the bezier circle but the problem I'm hitting is that the loop only finds one element. Shouldn't it find 4 as indicated in edit mode ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object has curve data. The curve data object holds a [*spline collection*](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Curve.html#bpy.types.Curve.splines).

In each spline there are [bezier_points](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Spline.html#bpy.types.Spline.bezier_points) or [points](http://ahttps://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Spline.html#bpy.types.Spline.bezier_points).

You have mistaken a bezier point for a spline. The spline is a continued element made up from multiple points. As a curve data object can hold multiple splines (they can be discontinued/separate), it has a spline collection.

You can access the points with the [Spline Info](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/spline/spline_info.html#spline-info) node. However if you want to produce a variable point list, I'd suggest inserting a script node which takes in a point list and outputs the modified point list.

Comment: thanks ! It then seems I can't find a way to loop through bezier points, I've found no mention of this, is that true ?

Comment: I was trying to add a bezier point in between each bezier point, by looping through all the bezier points, but I ended up just appending a bezier point at the end of the spline. Hence the one weird little guy at the end

Comment: Added a blurb at the end, helpful?

Comment: yes thanks a lot ! I'm starting to get things to work but this all seems very complicated using splines, I might just end up working with vertices instead and using splines just to smooth everything out at the end.

writting a script to subdivide between two points might be easier than writting a script to add a bezier point between two bezier points

thanks a lot for helping me unerstand more about splines

Comment: I did some scripting with beziers. Look at the first code snippet in [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144707/30849). It shows how to split a bezier (linked from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369488/splitting-a-bezier-curve/8405756#8405756)). Not *very* easy, but doable.