# Bezier Curve through points (script)

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves

I am new to scripting in Blender and I'd like to script a bezier curve by only using points as inputs (see image below from Wikipedia): 
[image]

Can anyone let me know how to do it? I have tried using the attributes (coordinates handle_left and handle_right) but it doesn't give me the right answer.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144707/31447

Comment: I've used it and generalized it. Thanks!