# Attaching mesh to curve messed up

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

Using

[What is the fastest way to add vertices to a curve at a specific point?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8808/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-add-vertices-to-a-curve-at-a-specific-point)

I've create a curve, and tried attaching a mesh with an array modifier set. This is what happened (.blend atached):

[image]

My guess is that where the tiles are merged, the "steps" of the curve are too close. Is there a way to make them equidistant?

[image]

Something identically related to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980166/equally-distribute-objects-across-a-bezier-curve

Answer (score 0):

> enable Loop Tools Addon (distributed with Blender)
> convert the curve to mesh (ALT+C) (Object Mode)
> Edit Mode
> select all vertices (A)
> set even spacing of verts: W > Loop Tools > Space
> Object Mode
> convert it back to curve

https://blenderartists.org/t/solved-is-there-a-way-to-evenly-distribute-splines-points-in-a-bezier-circle/1115092

urgh ...